# Terraform - how to avoid password for VM in the terraform script

Tags: terraform

Is there a way to avoid putting password in the Terraform script for the admin user of a Virtual Machine?

I dont want to put the password in the script and check-in it into the repo.

Answer (score 1):

Terraform supports passing variables to your scripts:

```
variable "vm_password" {
  description = "Your VM password"
}
```

These can be passed via environment variables prefixed with `TF_VAR_` (e.g. `TF_VAR_vm_password`). Or you can pass a tfvars file (which you then don't check in of course), which can be passed to terraform with the `-var-file` flag (e.g. `terraform apply -var-file=myvars.tfvars`). If none of these are specified, executing `terraform apply` will prompt for manual input of the variables.

Note that the secret is still checked in to your Terraform state file. So ensure your Terraform state file is stored in a secure location, or take extra measures to encrypt your state file.